# bash script counting lines

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script on a Linux machine to count lines and stop at `Firmware state: Rebuild`, then get that line number (e.g. 15 -1 = 14, since line number 0 is the first line) and save it in a variable. I don't know how to do this so looking for some help.

```
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Rebuild
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
```

---

Update

This has been working really well until we have found a issue if the hard drives are not attached from slot 0 it doesnt work correctly..

```
[root@la43 ~]# /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -PDList -aALL | grep -e "Firmware state" -e "Slot"
Slot Number: 4
Firmware state: Rebuild
Slot Number: 5
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 6
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 7
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 8
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 9
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 10
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 11
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 12
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 13
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 14
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Slot Number: 15
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
```

So what i need to is to get Slot Number 4 from the answer.
So would need to get Firmware state: Rebuild which is line 1 then -1 to get line 0 then get the Slot Number 4

So the var end ups being 4

How would i do this?

TIA

Comment: Where do those lines come from? stdout of some process? A file? A serial console?

Answer (score 7):

With `awk`:

```
$ var=$(awk '$0=="Firmware state: Rebuild"{print --NR; exit}' file)
$ echo "$var"
14
```

The `awk` script prints the input record number minus 1 when the current line equals `Firmware state: Rebuild` and exits the script.
The output of the command substitution `$(...)` is then assigned to variable `var`.

Comment: thanks you so much, got around to finish the code off and it works awesomely. i went with awk as i seem to like it.

Comment: @Wayno Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 5):

This should do what you want:

```
$ var=$(( $(grep -m1 -n 'Firmware state: Rebuild' file | cut -d: -f1) -1 ))
$ echo $var
14
```

#### Explanation

- `grep -m1 -n 'Firmware state: Rebuild'`: this will search for the first (`-m 1`) line matching `Firmware state: Rebuild`, and print that line including its line number (`-n`):

  ```
  $ grep -m1 -n 'Firmware state: Rebuild' file 
  15:Firmware state: Rebuild
  ```
- `cut -d: -f1`: the output of the `grep` above is then piped through this `cut` which takes `:` as the field delimiter and prints the first field, the line number. 
  *`var=$(( $(command) -1 ))`: The `$(( ))` construct lets us perform mathematical operations. For example:

  ```
  $ echo $((10-2))
  8
  ```

  The `$(command)` construct lets us use the *output* of a command as though it were a variable. So, `$(( $(command) -1 ))` will print the result of subtracting 1 from the output of `command`. Since `command` here is the `grep | cut` above, whose output is the line number (`15`), this will save the line number minus one as `$var`.

---

Note that the solution above will also match a line like `Firmware state: Rebuild again` or anything else that contains `Firmware state: Rebuild` as a substring. If you need to ensure it only matches when the entire line contains nothing but `Firmware state: Rebuild`, use this instead:

```
var=$(( $(grep -xm1 -n 'Firmware state: Rebuild' file | cut -d: -f1) -1 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var=$(grep -n "Firmware state: Rebuild" filename| awk -F ":" '{print $1-1}')
```

This is a variation of terdon's answer, using `awk` instead of `cut` and shell arithmetic to calculate the zero-based line number.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/Rebuild$/!d;=' file
```

Or using antipattern:

```
sed -n '/,/d;=' file
```

```
15
```

Prints the line number with the given pattern. In this case, additional mathematical actions are required.

```
sed -n '/Rebuild$/Q;=' file
```

Or using antipattern:

```
sed -n '/,/!Q;=' file
```

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Prints line numbers before match the pattern. Here it is possible to use the `q` command instead of the `Q` command.
It is necessary to separate the last value for example via the `| tail -1` command. Or in a more sophisticated way:

```
: $(sed -n '/,/!q;=' file)
echo $_
14
```